# how to make a logbook module

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a log book module in codeigniter using PHP. I have started making the CRUD.

However, my groupmate said i did the wrong thing. I don't have to add manually the activity of the user and the time.

In short, as soon as the user logs in and starts doing a specific activity, like add room, it will be automatically recorded in the logbook table.

my problem is how to create a log book that automatically records all the activities of every user and how to connect it to my db. any idea?

---

basically, that`s the idea there...but I needed the right code...

Here`s what I started so far. just an outline:

controller:

```
function addlog_entry(){

 //i don`t know what code to put here to automatically add the user`s activity
}

function logbook(){
   //this is the list of the log entries. i also don`t know the codes.

}


model:


function add_room(){
   .
   .
   .

  //after the user adds room, his activity will be recorded here:

 $this->addlog_entry();
}

//then i have the two functions again:

function add_log_entry(){

    //right codes
}

function log_book(){
   //right codes
}
```

...never mind the view. I can handle it...so that`s the main problem i have here. hope you can help me out or give me some example of codes related to this problem which i can use as reference. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you should try and record user actions in a history table

if the operation was succesful (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE), you should log it into your history table

for instance, i made a system that manages customer telephone services, i will record what user X did at the moment of time Y regarding client Z, generally speaking